# Unable to find a PHP related error in my Magento code

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I want to show a switch to my two different store views in the header of my Magento 1.9 installation. So I did some changes in my header.phtml file.

Here is the complete file: https://codeshare.io/5PzeeM. It was working fine in its original form. The extra code I added is at line 1-5 and 17-25. After adding the code, the magento starts showing a completely blank page. So I believe its probably a PHP syntax error. However, I cant seem to find it. Probably another set of eyes can look on the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's this code

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$storecode=Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
?>
```

The sort answer is, delete these two lines, you don't need them

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
```

Long answer...

First, You cannot get require the file **app/Mage.php** from your template file before the path is relative, for this to work the app folder would need to be located in the same directory as your template, this is not the case.

Second, you should never require the **app/Mage.php** in your custom code, this is done by Magento in the index.php. What you have to do to get the store code is override the original block which the template belongs to and create a custom method

```
public function getStoreCode() {
    return Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
}
```

then from your template you could call `$this->getStoreCode()`

Hope that helps

Comment: Ok, yeah you are right. Removing that code, removed the error. Thanks.